# Convert from wxmaxima to LaTeX

Tags: formatting, matrices, convert, maple2e, maxima

I typed a work using wx Maxima. I am really short on time. Is there a way I can convert wxmx/wxm file to LaTeX or PDF? Pls answers should be very basic (i.e a toddler can understand). Also this work includes long equations and matrices but no diagrams or tables,  just plain text.Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. // What do you want to do? E.g. copy calculations into a Latex document? Or drawings from wxMaxima? Please EDIT your question and add this kind of info there. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1 Export

The best way to do it seems to use `wxMaxima`'s `export` menu (File/Export).

Example:

Exporting this [image: equations]

results in that:
[image: latex export]

As you can see, the code generated is quite complex and certainly not intended to edit manually.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

%% Created with wxMaxima 22.04.0

\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  % PDFLaTeX or LaTeX 
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B5}{\ensuremath{\mu}}
\else
  %  XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newsavebox{\picturebox}
\newlength{\pictureboxwidth}
\newlength{\pictureboxheight}
\newcommand{\includeimage}[1]{
    \savebox{\picturebox}{\includegraphics{#1}}
    \settoheight{\pictureboxheight}{\usebox{\picturebox}}
    \settowidth{\pictureboxwidth}{\usebox{\picturebox}}
    \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\pictureboxwidth > .95\linewidth}}
    {
        \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth,height=.80\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}
    }
    {
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\pictureboxheight>.80\textheight}}
        {
            \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth,height=.80\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}
            
        }
        {
            \includegraphics{#1}
        }
    }
}
\newlength{\thislabelwidth}
\DeclareMathOperator{\abs}{abs}

\definecolor{labelcolor}{RGB}{100,0,0}

\begin{document}


\noindent
%%%%%%%%
%% INPUT:
\begin{minipage}[t]{4.000000em}\color{red}\bfseries
 --\ensuremath{\ensuremath{>}}  
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}\color{blue}
R:\ s\ /\ phi;\\
D:\ (R-x)\ *\ (1-cos(phi));
\end{minipage}
%%%% OUTPUT:
\[\displaystyle \tag{R} 
\frac{s}{phi}\mbox{}\]

\[\tag{D} 
\left( 1-\cos{(phi)}\right) \, \left( \frac{s}{phi}-x\right) \mbox{}
\]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\noindent
%%%%%%%%
%% INPUT:
\begin{minipage}[t]{4.000000em}\color{red}\bfseries
 --\ensuremath{\ensuremath{>}}  
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}\color{blue}
trigreduce(\%);
\end{minipage}
%%%% OUTPUT:
\[\displaystyle \tag{\% o6} 
\cos{(phi)} x-x-\frac{\cos{(phi)} s}{phi}+\frac{s}{phi}\mbox{}
\]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\noindent
%%%%%%%%
%% INPUT:
\begin{minipage}[t]{4.000000em}\color{red}\bfseries
 --\ensuremath{\ensuremath{>}}  
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}\color{blue}
factor(\%);
\end{minipage}
%%%% OUTPUT:
\[\displaystyle \tag{\% o7} 
\frac{\left( \cos{(phi)}-1\right) \, \left( phi x-s\right) }{phi}\mbox{}
\]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\noindent
%%%%%%%%
%% INPUT:
\begin{minipage}[t]{4.000000em}\color{red}\bfseries
 --\ensuremath{\ensuremath{>}}  
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}\color{blue}
radcan(\%);
\end{minipage}
%%%% OUTPUT:
\[\displaystyle \tag{\% o8} 
\frac{\left( phi \cos{(phi)}-phi\right)  x+\left( 1-\cos{(phi)}\right)  s}{phi}\mbox{}
\]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\noindent
%%%%%%%%
%% INPUT:
\begin{minipage}[t]{4.000000em}\color{red}\bfseries
 --\ensuremath{\ensuremath{>}}  
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}\color{blue}
delta:\ (1-cos(phi))\ *\ s/phi\ -\ (1\ -\ cos(phi)/phi);
\end{minipage}
%%%% OUTPUT:
\[\displaystyle \tag{delta} 
\frac{\left( 1-\cos{(phi)}\right)  s}{phi}+\frac{\cos{(phi)}}{phi}-1\mbox{}
\]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\noindent
%%%%%%%%
%% INPUT:
\begin{minipage}[t]{4.000000em}\color{red}\bfseries
 --\ensuremath{\ensuremath{>}}  
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}\color{blue}
trigsimp(delta);
\end{minipage}
%%%% OUTPUT:
\[\displaystyle \tag{\% o14} 
-\frac{\left( \cos{(phi)}-1\right)  s-\cos{(phi)}+phi}{phi}\mbox{}
\]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

### 2 Listings

As an alternative you can use package `listing` to copy equations into your Latex editor, like below. HOWEVER, this one still doesn't compile because you have to remove all multiplication dots. It may be useful on occasion.

(You may want to chose a different language than PHP. Have a look into the manual.)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=PHP,breaklines=true}
 \begin{lstlisting}
 -->    R: s / phi;
    D: (R-x) * (1-cos(phi));
(R) s/phi
(D) (1-cos(phi))(s/phi-x)
 -->    trigreduce(%);
(%o6)   cos(phi)x-x-(cos(phi) s)/phi+s/phi
 -->    factor(%);
(%o7)   ((cos(phi)-1)·(phi·x-s))/phi
 -->    radcan(%);
(%o8)   ((phi·cos(phi)-phi)x+(1-cos(phi))·s)/phi
 -->    delta: (1-cos(phi)) * s/phi - (1 - cos(phi)/phi);
(delta) ((1-cos(phi))·s)/phi+cos(phi)/phi-1
 -->    trigsimp(delta);
(%o14)  -((cos(phi)-1)·s-cos(phi)+phi)/phi 
 \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

### 3 pdf

Just print your wxmx file (File/Print). To do so your system needs to have a pdf-printer installed. Don't know, how good or bad the pdfs will be.